# Book references for beginners in Fourier series and/or linear algebra with programming section

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, fourier-series, book-recommendation

I am looking for good book references for beginners to study Fourier series and/or linear algebra but with a programming section (such as "Introduction to probability" by Blitztein with an "R" section dedicated to programming in R language some of the probability concepts)to apply concepts either for understand better the concepts or for solve excercises.

(If you know some math book that has programming stuff, even if it's not about Fourier series or linear algebra, let me know it too)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking out [Coding the Matrix: Linear Algebra through Applications to Computer Science](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0615880991) by Klein.

You could also check out [Linear Algebra: Theory, Intuition, Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9083136604) by Cohen.